# How to implement conditions for logging levels in the log attribute class in a web API project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, logging, log4net

In my web API project, I have created a MyFilterAttribute class which is inherited from ActionFilterAttribute.

I have mentioned the log messages for the HttpMethod GET as follows

```
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;

namespace Resume
{
    public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
        {
            if (actionContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
            {
                var log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ApiController));
                log.Info("This is log meassage for GET method");
                log.Warn("This is a warn log message for a GET method");
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My GET method in the EmployeeController is like:

```
[Route("{eid}")]
[HttpGet]
[MyFilterAttribute]
public HttpResponseMessage GetEmployee(int eid)
  {
     var employee = _unitOfWork.Employee.GetById(eid);
     if (employee != null)
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, employee);
     else
         return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "Employee with Id " + eid + " does not exist");
        }
```

My GET method in the CompanyController is like:

```
[Route("{cid}")]
[HttpGet]
[MyFilterAttribute]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCompany(int cid)
  {
     var company = _unitOfWork.Company.GetById(eid);
     if (company != null)
         return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, company);
     else
         return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, "company with Id " + cid + " does not exist");
        }
```

Whenever a get request is made to any controller both the log messages are getting logged.

Can anyone help in mentioning the conditions for logging in different controllers with different log levels

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `Enum` for `LogLevel` and then use it:

```
public class MyFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public LogLevel LogLevel { get; set; }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (actionContext.Request.Method == HttpMethod.Get)
        {
            var log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(ApiController));
            if(LogLevel.Verbose)
            {
               log.Info("This is log meassage for GET method");
               log.Warn("This is a warn log message for a GET method");
            }
            if(LogLevel.Info)
                log.Info("This is log meassage for GET method");
            if(LogLevel.Warning)
                 log.Warn("This is a warn log message for a GET method");
        }

    }
}
```

and your Enum will be like:

```
public enum LogLevel
{
     Information,
     Warning,
     Verbose
}
```

Use it on action like:

```
[MyFilterAttribute(LogLevel = LogLevel.Verbose)]
public HttpResponseMessage GetCompany(int cid)
{
```

Hope it gives you idea.

Comment: How the logger will come to know which log level need to be selected for a specific mothed in a controller?

Comment: by setting the `LogLevel` parameter on controller method